# Convert Size.Width and Size.Height to millimeter

Tags: c#, gdi+

I have requirement to measure the text length in a PDF and wrap the line if the length exceeds a certain amount.

I already used the following code to determine length of the text (not sure it's working as expected but I need to solve another problem beforehand).

```
public static Size MeasureString(string s, Font font)
{
    SizeF result;
    using (var image = new Bitmap(1, 1))
    {
        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(image))
        {
            result = g.MeasureString(s, font);
        }
    }
    return result.ToSize();
}
```

The return value of this Method is an instance of `Size` class. I am wondering how to convert `Height` and `Width` properties of this class to a human readable unit like millimeter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert a `Size`, which is in pixels, to a "real life value" in milimeters you need one additional value:
**dpi** - dots per inch.

This should be defined by your PDF class. As soon as you have this value you can calculate the value you want:

```
const double milimetresPerInch = 25.4; // as one inch is 25.4 mm
double lengthInMilimeter = size.Width / dpi * milimetresPerInch;
```